# Phonegap SMSComposer confusion

Tags: ios, cordova

Stuck with the `SMSComposer` plugin. I have followed all the steps with adding keys to the plugin list and downloading the files. It is the most recent version from github and it has me confused. I understood the old one better. How do I specify `toRecipients` and `body`?

```
function SMSComposer()
{
    this.resultCallback = null;
}

SMSComposer.ComposeResultType =
{
Cancelled:0,
Sent:1,
Failed:2,
NotSent:3
}

SMSComposer.prototype.showSMSComposer = function(toRecipients, body)
{

    var args = {};

    if(toRecipients)
        args.toRecipients = toRecipients;

    if(body)
        args.body = body;

    Cordova.exec("SMSComposer.showSMSComposer",args);
}

SMSComposer.prototype.showSMSComposerWithCB = function(cbFunction,toRecipients,body)
{
    this.resultCallback = cbFunction;
    this.showSMSComposer.apply(this,[toRecipients,body]);
}

SMSComposer.prototype._didFinishWithResult = function(res)
{
    this.resultCallback(res);
}

Cordova.addConstructor(function() {

                       if(!window.plugins)  {
                       window.plugins = {};
                       }
                       window.plugins.smsComposer = new SMSComposer();
                       });
```

.

```
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
                </div <center><button onclick="cordova.exec(null,null, 'SMSComposer','showSMSComposer',[args])">Compose SMS</button></center>

                >
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="SMSComposer.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                app.initialize();

                var args;

                // cordova.exec(null,null, 'SMSComposer','showSMSComposer',[args]);



                </script>

            </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: 
There is no reaction when I press the `button`. No error message in the console.

Answer (score 3):

try this: 
https://github.com/wesson818/SMSPluginForCordova2.3.0
you are able to pass message body and select recipients in Android native message app.

Answer (score 0):

@ P A Hemingstam 
If you replace "Cordova" with "cordova" in SMSComposer.js file then it will work. :)